# Python - Merge two lists of tuples into one

Tags: python

I have two lists of tuples and i want to merge them into one
Ex :
List1 = [(a, 1),(b,2)]
List2 =[(a, 3),(b,4)]
I want theresult to be
Result = [(a, 1,3),(b,2,4)]

Comment: tuples are immutable - you would have to reconstruct them. what did you try to solve it?

Comment: Do you mean a tuple starts with a should match another tuple that starts with a?  Do they always appear at same order in the two lists.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 3
>>> l1 = [(a, 1),(b,2)]
>>> l2 = [(a, 3),(b,4)]
>>> result = []
>>> for i1,i2 in zip(l1,l2):
    result.append(tuple([i1[0]])+tuple(i1[1:])+tuple(i2[1:]))

>>> result
[(1, 1, 3), (3, 2, 4)]
>>>
```